# Need help on writing a Phrase or line in the Lyrics

Tags: poetry, lyrics

This is the original line, " **I have anger and sorrow for you**  "

I have to rewrite this line in a rhythmic format
Line should intrigue a person

Need some help from the experts

Comment: That sentiment should not be compressed into a single short line.  It should be given space commensurate with it's significance.

Comment: There's not enough detail here. What "rhythmic format"? What do you mean by "intrigue a person"? Please note that Stack Exchange answers are supposed to be as objective as possible (even in an Arts subject like ELU), so it's important to give as much help as you can to enable answerers to give exactly what you need. To that end, you might want to [read, "should"] give as much detail as possible about the context: where this line is to be used; whether it's poetry or prose; whether it's a loving billet-doux or a poison-pen letter. Anything and everything which might possibly be useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for writing advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the preceding and following lines would be incredibly helpful.

Nevertheless:

**Your reflection/face shines in my furious/burning tears.**

Comment: We are working on a music and need some lines. I am really impressed on your quote. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

How about, **"I've felt anger and sorrow towards you"**? This suggestion reflects the fact that one usually doesn't say, "I have anger for you."

Another possibility might be the following: **"My heart is filled with anger and sorrow when I think of you."** It all depends what will work with the surrounding  lyrics.

In ten words, **"Why do anger and sorrow fill my heart for you?"** Still too many syllables? How about, **"I ache with anger and sorrow for you."**

Comment: thank you. line has to be phrase. Your second quote is impressive. Still i try to get it in less than 10 words

Comment: i think, my original line is much touchy and i expect the words closer to my line. Possibly in riddle format

Comment: Woow @mark .. i like that .., I ache with anger and sorrow for you .. :)

Comment: "I endure anger and feel sorrow for you" ?